# How to create my own file extension like .odt or .doc?

Tags: java, file, file-extension

I am working on a document processing project like Microsoft word (Academic project).

Is there any quick way to create my own file extension? Is there third-party software that allows you to create your own file extension? (I.e. myfile.funny?)

Comment: What do you meant "how to create my own file extension"? Extension is just part of file name. If you want extension like "ext" just name file like "myFile.ext".

Comment: If my file is Zip.The file will not allow to unzip normally.

Comment: If your expectation is that adding a .zip file extension will make a zip file then you need a little more research on how it all works.

Comment: Of course not! The zip files have some specific properties

Comment: @user1853875 just changing extension of file wont change its inner structure. For example if you change extension of some image file like "someImage.jpg" to "someImage.zip" it wont make/convert it to zip archive, but simply change its name so it wont be valid zip file.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/365596/make-and-run-your-own-file-extensionhttps://superuser.com/questions/365596/make-and-run-your-own-file-extension

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A file extension is just the portion of the file name after the last period.

For example in the path:

`C:\Users\Tests\My Documents\file.txt`

The file extension is `.txt` which typically indicates that the file contains text data.
 To create your own file extension all you need to do is to place the desired extension after the last period in the filename.

In Java you can create a file using an object of type `File` like this:

```
File file = new File("file.txt")
```

The file will be created in the current working directory and will have the extension `txt` because this is the value after the final period in the file name.

A file format refers to the layout of data inside a file. Creating a custom file format involves thinking about how you want to store your data within the file, and writing it to the file in a way which matches that layout.

For example
if I had an address book application I might decide to store peoples names and phone numbers, separated by tabs and save this data in a file with extension `address`

My  `AddressBook.Save()` function might look something like this Java code. It should be noted that I haven't programmed in Java for a number of years and mistakes are likely.

```
void Save(File file)
{
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

foreach (AddressBookEntry entry in this.entries)
{
this.SaveEntry(entry,writer);
}
} 


void SaveEntry(AddressBookEntry entry,  FileWriter writer)
{
  String record = entry.getFirstName() + "\t" + entry.getLastName() + "\t" +
  entry.getPhoneNumber();
  writer.write(record, 0, record.length();
}
```

If we had an address entry like this:

```
First Name:Test
Last Name: Bob
Phone Number=555-1212
```

Then the entry would appear in the `.address` file as follows

`Test   Bob 555-1212`

I hope that's helped explain the difference between a file extension and a file format and has gone some way to showing you how to create your own format, with a custom extension.

Answer (score 4):

This is not `Java` related. Pick an extension that no one else is using and when you write the file using `Java`, just append the extension to the filename.

Answer (score 3):

If would suggest following someone else's format like .odt or even HTML for something like this. If you are serious about creating your own format then you should take a look through java's inbuilt xml libraries and make a format using xml, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ is a good place to start then browse to the javax.xml.* packages.
Like other's have said if you just want to change the file extension, just put you extension at the end of the file path. 
Getting the OS to associate your program with that extension is a lot more complicated though and not really a java issue, it is also platform dependent.