# How to save a file with custom extension?

Tags: java, file-io

I am working on a project which creates a file with `.bat` extension.

In C++ it is possible by using

```
fstream myfile ("example.bat");
fstream<<"echo \"hello\" ";
```

But how can I do it in Java (JDK 8)?

Comment: check out this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412942/how-to-create-my-own-file-extension-like-odt-or-doc and this http://superuser.com/questions/529649/how-do-i-make-a-custom-file-extension-open-my-java-program

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading up on [Java File IO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm). Whatever you want to call the file you're saving, you can. There aren't any *custom extensions* as opposed to *normal* extensions.

[Additional Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this code does what you want. `createFile` will throw `FileAlreadyExistsException` if specified file already exists.

```
Path myBat = Paths.get("example.bat");
Files.createFile(myBat);
try( BufferedWriter reader = Files.newBufferedWriter(myBat) ) {
    reader.append("hello");
}
```

**Edit:**

I think try-with-resources is needed here.

Comment: For working of this code the example.bat file should be present already. But I want it to create a new file not append the existing one

Comment: Two first lines create new file. After the creation you append to it (it's empty initially). `Paths::get` method only throws exception if the string you provide cannot be converted to valid path ex. `sdhsa%^$(@*@&(W?@`. So `example.bat file should be present already` is incorrect. It needs to be present to create `BufferedWriter`. What I meant is you can't with this snippet create file `example.bat` if it already exists.